# "惡" vs "噩" vs "厄"

Tags: word-choice, meaning, usage, difference, meaning-in-context

I have seen these three characters forming the "same" words (I cannot think of a better way to phrase this), such as

> 惡夢 vs 噩夢

and

> 惡運 vs 噩運 vs 厄運

As I tried googling for the difference, I find different opinions on their meaning/usage – some argue that they are interchangeable; others claim that they are slightly different. [Below](http://www.zhihu.com/question/20016153) is what I thought to be the best explanation I have found by far:

> 噩: 不祥.
>   厄: 灾难.
>   恶: 恶劣.
>
> 不祥不一定就会发生灾难, 但灾难必定是不祥的, 而这两者都很恶劣.

However, the explanation still sounds rather vague to me. In explicit, how do these characters differ in meaning/usage?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.jxteacher.com/zhaoxiaoli/column57436/d52fe790-21d4-4c7c-a529-39bf621a6086.html “恶梦”侧重梦的凶险、不祥，强调梦的内容；“噩梦”侧重梦的惊恐，强调心理感受。如“那场~至今难忘”，用前者为好；“我从~中惊醒”，以后者为宜。

Comment: http://www.360doc.com/content/13/0715/09/3918785_300060620.shtml
1、厄运  比较官方的语言
2、噩运  侧重不幸（凄惨）的命运，一般伴随着人的伤亡和疾病
3、恶运  不常用，指坏的运气，不一定是不幸的

Comment: I am a Chinese, but I can't tell the difference.

Comment: I'm a Chinese, I use "厄运" because this is the only one in my pinyin input method. and by the way, many questions here let me rethink if i'm really a Chinese.

Comment: [è] using 爱词霸、小马词典。顺便一提＂汉语水平考试词典＂没有＂噩、厄＂条目，只有＂恶＂ 
噩: 1. （形）凶恶惊人的。shocking ； upsetting 
compounds：噩梦、噩耗、噩运 variant of 厄运 
厄: 2. （灾难；困苦） adversity; disaster; hardship  动1. （受困） be in distress; be stranded The fishing boat was caught in a storm. 渔船厄于风暴。
厄widely used for transliterating foreign names e。g。厄立特里亚
恶:  <名> （很坏的行为； 犯罪的事情） evil ； vice ； wickedness <形> fierce ； ferocious ； bad ； evil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you know? 厄 is a 象形字, a pictogram. It is said that about 4 percent of the characters in the Chinese are derived directly from individual pictograms, but most of the characters are [pictophonetics](http://www.digmandarin.com/four-main-types-of-chinese-characters.html).

厄 is akin to 困厄 or 遭遇困境, such as "being between a rock and a hard place," or being in difficult situation.

There's not much to say about 恶 really. In my opinion, it pertains to 凶恶 stuff, usually brought on as a consequence of one's own actions (akin to "karma") that unrelated to one's fortune (运程).

噩 is as other have described in the comments an adjective meaning 惊人的 or 可怕的; basically something frightening or shocking.